# How to access Google Datastore API with credentials without using environment variables?

Tags: google-app-engine, authentication, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-platform

Currently I'm getting access to the API though the GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS environment variable. I created and downloaded a service account key as a .json file and set the environment variable to that file. Due to the requirements of the project I'm working on, I won't be able to do this. I tried using the credentials variable in the constructor for the datastore client object, but I wasn't able to get that to work. How should I be going about this?

I'm running Windows 10, but any solution should be (relatively) OS agnostic. I'm writing in python 3.6.

Comment: Have you followed the instructions on https://google-cloud-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/core/auth.html#explicit-credentials and https://google-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user-guide.html#service-account-private-key-files. If not, try it out. If problem persists, post the code/results/errors.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `from_service_account_json()`:

```
from google.cloud import datastore

client = datastore.Client.from_service_account_json('/path/to/credentials.json')
var = client.get(client.key('MyKind', '<key value>'))
print(var)
```

see: https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production#obtaining_and_providing_service_account_credentials_manually